# UILongPressGestureRecognizer with different buttons

Tags: iphone, xcode, button

I have 2 buttons with "UILongPressGestureRecognizer", to do it, i do:

Fot button 1:

```
-(IBAction)seleccionar46:(id)sender{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture =[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3;
[longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
[self.button1 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];}
```

For button 2:

```
    -(IBAction)seleccionar46:(id)sender{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture =[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3;
[longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
[self.button2 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];}
```

And in "longpressGesture" i need differentiate between button1 and button2, but i can´t do it...

```
 - (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{//Here i need do the differentation}
```

Thanks for all!

Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is use the `view` property of `UIGestureRecognizer`, so if you save a reference to both your buttons, you can check for equality.

So if you have

```
@interface blah
{
  UIButton *buttonOne;
  UIButton *buttonTwo;
}
```

then you add the recognizers to the buttons you can do in the handler

```
if(gestureRecognizer.view==buttonOne)
{
   //do stuff for button one
}
else if(gestureRecognizer.view==buttonTwo)
{
  //do stuff for button two
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks friend!I need save the name of button in an NSSttring ... How can i do this?

Comment: Because the name of the button is the same that the name of one image... And when i press the button for 3 seconds, it show the image associate to the button... I hope you can understanme... Thanks for all Daniel

Comment: well you should keep some sort of dictionary or something to keep track of that, or hard code it if theres only one image per button and its static

Comment: They are only one image per button, but i cant understand "hard core"... Could you give me an example? Thanks Daniel